# Angular provider - $animate is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, jquery-animate, provider

Why is this not working? `$animate.leave` doesn't know what to 'leave', causing multiple instances of my new element. Why is that happening?

`ng-notify.js`

```
angular.module('ngNotify', [])
    .provider('ngNotify', function () {

        this.$get = ['$injector', '$document', '$rootScope', function ($injector, $document, $rootScope) {

            this.show = function(){

                var $animate;

                if (!$animate) {
                    $animate = $injector.get('$animate');
                 }

                var bodyElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'))
                var redBlockElement = angular.element('<div class="red block"></div>')

                // close previous instances
                $animate.leave(redBlockElement);

                $animate.enter(redBlockElement, bodyElement).then(function() {                  
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                });

            }
            return this;
        }];

});
```

I load this code as a seperate JS to my main app. This is how my `app.js` file looks

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp ',[
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',
    'LocalStorageModule',
    'angularMoment',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'angular.morris-chart',
    'mgo-angular-wizard',
    'myApp.version',
    'ngNotify', // the dependency I'm trying to create
])
```

**

### update

**

I took the variables outside `show()` and the duplicate problem solved. But how can I make my message dynamic?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ngNotify', [])
.provider('ngNotify', function () {

    this.$get = ['$injector', '$document', '$timeout', '$rootScope', '$animate', function ($injector, $document, $timeout, $rootScope, $animate) {

        var html = '<div class="ng-notify">' + text + '</div>'; // text has to be dynamic

        var tmpl = angular.element(html);
        var body = $document.find('body').eq(0);
        var bodyElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'));

        this.show = function(text){
            $animate.enter(tmpl, body);
        }

        return this;
    }];

});
```

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code you have posted. Is that really the code you are using? Otherwise please show it.

Comment: Yes, it is all of my code. I should mention I load this code as seperate JS as a dependency of my app. I added some more code, check it out if you can.

Comment: You are not injecting`$animate` and there is a comma missing between `$document` and `$location`, which is why I assumed this was not the code you are using.

Comment: code edited, still not working..

Comment: Can you describe what the code is supposed to do? Is there an element with `class="red block"` already present that you want removed? Should it remove all if more than one is present?

Comment: Here's what it should do - once calling `ngNotify.show();` - I want to throw the `red block` div to my html and delete previous divs. I'm able to create the div, but not delete. Something about `$animate.leave()` isn't right in my code. What happens is that I get that div duplicated over and over again when I call `.show() ` function.

Comment: Should it be possible to have more than one of these divs present? Or always just one?

Comment: Just one. Imagine a unique message for website. I want to display it only once, and when I call it again with different message, I want the previous one to disapear.

Comment: Alright, will post answer soon.

Comment: thank you so much for your patience. Sorry I wasn't too sharp about my description. looking forward for a solution, it's been 2 days almost that I'm stuck..

Comment: No worries, just want to make sure I understand what you are after :)

Comment: I just tried to take all my variables outside of `show()` and it actually stopped duplicating my element without even using `$animate.leave()`. I'm not sure why, I'm walking in the darkness here.. But this information  might help you. Keep in mind that the message needs to be dynamic (eventually, `show()` will receive an argument called `text`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that each time `show` is called, the following code will create a new element:

```
var redBlockElement = angular.element('<div class="red block"></div>')
```

This element will not be attached to the DOM yet, so passing it to `$animate.leave` will not achieve anything, as there is nothing to remove.

Then the element is passed to `$animate.enter` and is attached to the DOM.

So each time `show` is called, a new element will be created and added.

One solution is to move the following lines so they are only called once:

```
var bodyElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'));
var redBlockElement = angular.element('<div class="red block">Test</div>');

this.show = function() { ...
```

Then always work with the `redBlockElement` reference, passing it to `leave`, `enter` or change its text value.

If you want to them to be different elements each time you can either keep a reference to the previous element created and remove it before creating and adding a new one, or simply query the DOM and remove it:

```
var bodyElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'));

this.show = function() {

  var existing = angular.element(bodyElement[0].querySelector('.red.block'));

  $animate.leave(existing);

  var redBlockElement = angular.element('<div class="red block"></div>');

  $animate.enter(redBlockElement, bodyElement).then(function() {
    $rootScope.$apply();
  });
};
```

Note that this example only removes one existing element, even if there are multiple.

Comment: How can I change the value of redBlockElement inside of `show()`? (Keep in mind that `show()` gets an argument, so that `Test` is basically dynami text. If i'll declare `redBlockElement` again, it will make a new element and ignore my previous one. (which results duplicated elements)

Comment: This should work: `redBlockElement.text(someVariable)`

Comment: declaring angular.element must be outside the function from what I understand otherwise it still gets duplicated, look - http://i.imgur.com/nXT6in7.png (fully using your recent code)

Comment: you are RIGHT, omg its my bad, im sorry. WOW it's working thank you so much for your patience, you didn't give up even when i gave up on myself :( haha much appreciated sir!